# Date of "Last updated on..." is not the same in local preview and when deployed

Tags: r, yaml, blogdown

I moved my blog articles to my personal website. For an unknown reason, when I run locally my website (and open it in the browser), the date in "Last updated on..." is correct, i.e it is the `date` argument I put in the YAML.

However, when I push this to GitHub and deploy it through Netlify, all the articles have the mention "Last updated on Sep 22, 2020" (i.e today at the time of writing). Adding the `lastmod` argument in the YAML has no influence on this.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: I use the academic theme. More precisely, I cloned [Alison Hill's repo](https://github.com/rbind/apreshill), and replaced her content / images / css by mine. That's why I don't understand why I have this problem and she hasn't.

Comment: I quickly made a pull request for your git repo - try if this works (see also my answer below for the explanation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is, because the 'Last updated on' date is taken from your Git commit.

You can configure which dates are taken by adding a `frontmatter` section to your `config.toml`.

The default is:

```
[frontmatter]
date = ["date", "publishDate", "lastmod"]
lastmod = [":git", "lastmod", "date", "publishDate"]
publishDate = ["publishDate", "date"]
expiryDate = ["expiryDate"]
```

Which means, if available, the git commit date is taken. Running locally you don't have it, so it would take the `lastmod` setting. If you don't set `lastmod` locally it takes the `date`.

I think it should be enough if you add this section to your `config.toml` and change the order.

E.g.

```
[frontmatter]
date = ["date", "publishDate", "lastmod"]
lastmod = ["lastmod", "date", ":git", "publishDate"]
publishDate = ["publishDate", "date"]
expiryDate = ["expiryDate"]
```

Here is more information about the topic from the official documentation:
https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#configure-dates